# If hasClass condition not working jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find out how to show/hide an element depending on the fact whether the element ".question a" has the class "checked" or not. But it isn't working. Anybody knows why ;( ?

```
$().ready(function() {

    var myLink = ".question a";
    if (myLink.hasClass('checked')) { 
        $('.answer').show(300);
    }
    else {
        $('.answer').hide(300);
    }   

});
```

Comment: `var myLink = $(".question a");`

Comment: how many questions will be there in a page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myLink = $(".question a");
    if (myLink.hasClass('checked')) { //You can also use $(this).hasClass
        $('.answer').show(300);
    }
    else {
        $('.answer').hide(300);
    }   
});
```

If you want to change the status of link then call the same while your event triggered like

```
$(myLink).on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) { 
        $('.answer').show(300);
    }
    else {
        $('.answer').hide(300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's partially working. The problem is that now it's hidden as default and it doesn't reflect the state of the link class. In firebug I see that it's changing from to `class="checked"` to nothing (and back again depending how many times I clicked) when clicking on it. But the `.answer` is always hidden. Any idea why? Btw. I have only on `.question a`element(link)

Comment: Then you need to check the class when you are changing the state of link class also

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {

    var myLink = $(".question a"); // need to use jQuery selector here
    if (myLink.hasClass('checked')) { 
        $('.answer').show(300);
    }
    else {
        $('.answer').hide(300);
    }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Repalce**

```
var myLink = ".question a";
```

**With**

```
var myLink = $(".question a");
```

Answer (score 0):

add `$` before myLink

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myLink = ".question a";
    if ($(myLink).hasClass('checked')) { 
        $('.answer').show(300);
    }
    else {
        $('.answer').hide(300);
    }   

});
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it's always hidden now ;( even though the class is changing from "checked" to nothing.

Comment: write example in jsfiddle.net